# Remove Visual Search feature from Edge programatically

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, model-view-controller

Edge seems to have recently come out with a Visual Search feature, which pops up an icon above all images, allowing you to search for them etc. Very nice. See screenshot:

[image]

However, is it possible to switch this off via javascript or something similar? I am running a website where users are meant to click images as part of a personality profile mechanism, which is very sensitive to the selection environment. This distraction is very much unwanted.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. do any other browsers have any features like this I should watch out for?

Comment: Oh great! When you hover over an image of a razor blade on my website it suggests 'Geniune Toyota Tacoma Door Sill Protectors'. Now the image search is nice - and it does look like a door sill protector the way its cropped - but it's completely out of place :-/

Comment: @Simon_Weaver yes, a very unfortunate, unwanted feature that indeed can ruin the tone of a site, and as you have shown, can even come to mock it

Comment: I disabled it so I'm not tracking how it works. Is it really still active by default :-(

Answer (score 12):

#### Please report your dislike of this feature to Microsoft!

Everybody who comes to this page PLEASE report this to Microsoft.

Click the 3 dots that appears on top of the image and choose 'Send Feedback'.

This is not OK without a CSS / meta tag workaround to disable it.

I'll happily delete this answer if a way to disable it in code is discovered - but in the meantime we need to nip it in the bud - so please report it. Sorry this isn't really an answer - but if you've found this question you're probably as annoyed as me right now!

Comment: Count me in the "annoyed" bucket.  Spend time designing a clean UI without extra unnecessary buttons and icons, and some browser developer with his gimmick-of-the-week goes "I don't think so"

Comment: Absolutely "annoyed" on a website that is designed to serve images - and NOT, repeat NOT suggest that the user LEAVE the current website - or at least the current DOMAIN! Chalk one more up for the it ain't broke so let's fix it.

Comment: And please don't do pointer-events: none. It's not a good solution...

Answer (score 2):

Had some success in turning off pointer events on the img using css `pointer-events: none` and haven't found a better solution thus far.

Comment: Thanks, although this also prevents the click event, which I need. But it's an avenue to explore

Comment: It also prevents `title` / alt text from showing. I have an image carousel where it appears on each image which is a literal disaster.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have problems because `pointer-events: none` (css) disables the click event. If you wrap your picture in an extra div-container and wrap this div-container into an a-tag, the picture will behave like a link.  The structure will look like this:

```
<a href="/">
    <div>
        <img src="logo.png" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Not a beauty, but it works. Don't know if workarounds like this are possible for all pointer-events.